# SelectedItem not Loading on DataGrid Load

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that has a selection of `Jobs` that users can add/update/delete. My problem with my `DataGrid` is that when the data is loaded into it, I want it to automatically fill in some `TextBoxes` with details of the first item in the `DataGrid`. I do this by writing the method for the `SelectionChanged` event on the `DataGrid`;

```
    private void DataGridSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedJob = dataGrid.SelectedItem as JobModel;
            //MessageBox.Show(selectedJob.ITName);
            if (selectedJob != null)
            {
                notesTextBox.Text = selectedJob.CaseNotes;
                createdPicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(selectedJob.DateCreated.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                deadlinePicker.SelectedDate = DateTime.Parse(selectedJob.DateDeadline.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
                nameTextBox.Text = selectedJob.CaseClient;
                itNameComboBox.SelectedItem = selectedJob.ITName;
            }
        }
```

The issue here is that the `TextBoxes` (and `DatePickers`) are not filled in when the `DataGrid` loads. However, if I uncomment the `MessageBox` then the data is filled in correctly. This is a big problem as if there is only one job in the `DataGrid` then the user cannot select it to delete or update it. Here is the  `XAML` for the `DataGrid` itself;

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="true" 
                      Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="18.667" 
                      HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                      CanUserAddRows="False"
                      IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
                      EnableRowVirtualization="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding JobsCollectionView}"
                      MinColumnWidth="0" SelectionChanged="DataGridSelectionChanged">
                <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overdue}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <!--<DataGridTextColumn Header="Case NO" Width="*" Binding="{Binding CaseNumber}"/>!-->
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="IT Person" Width="*" Binding="{Binding ITName}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Case Notes" Width="*" Binding="{Binding CaseNotes}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date Created" Width="*" Binding="{Binding DateCreated, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deadline Date" Width="*" Binding="{Binding DateDeadline, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Employee Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding CaseClient}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

And the method that fills the `DataGrid`;

```
    public void FillDataGrid()
    {
        _jobDataService = new JobDataService();
        var _jobs = new ObservableCollection<JobModel>();
        _jobs = _jobDataService.GetJobList();
        JobsCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_jobs);
        DataContext = this;
        foreach (JobModel currentJob in JobsCollectionView)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now == currentJob.DateDeadline)
            {
                currentJob.Overdue = 0;
            }
            else if (DateTime.Now > currentJob.DateDeadline)
            {
                currentJob.Overdue = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there something obvious I am missing that is preventing the `SelectionChanged` event from being called? I find it strange how if I uncomment the `MessageBox` it works as I intended.

Comment: Try putting `MessageBox.Show(selectedJob.ITName);` at the last line of method `DataGridSelectionChanged`.

Comment: @user1672994 if its on the last line then it doesn't load the data into the `TextBoxes`. The point here is that I don't want to have to display a message box just to get the data to bind to the `TextBoxes`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this question myself by completely removing the `SelectionChanged` event. Instead I bind the UI elements in the `XAML` like so;

```
<TextBox x:Name="notesTextBox" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.CaseNotes, ElementName=dataGrid}" Margin="5" FontSize="21.333" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Binding to the `SelectedItem` in `XAML` works correctly now.